# YTD is not displaying in my Excel

Tags: ssas

What should be my expression in my New calculated member for "YearToDate"? Is it

```
[Measures].[Weekly-NRx]
```

or

```
SUM(YTD([DIM TIME].[Dates].CurrentMember),[Measures].[Weekly-NRx])
```

or

```
SUM(YTD(), [Measures].[Weekly-NRx] )>?
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To get Excel Pivot Tables to show calculated members, you have to set this in the options. To do this (I hope you can find the locations as I have a German version of Excel only and try to translate the names to English, but they might actually be named differently):

- Right-click on the pivot table
- Select "Pivot Table Options"
- Select "Display"
- Check "Display calculated members from OLAP Server"

However, calculated members in a non-measure hierarchy can only be switched on all together or switched off, no single selection is possible. Whatever caused the Excel developers to design it like this behavior.